# text extraction and manipulation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, text

I am trying to manipulate a field in my data so that it can be further processed. I am using MS SQL Server.

Example

```
Field_Name 
EEABC1233435666684
```

I wold like the new field New_Field to have only have the sub string of length 6 starting from the third character. Also I would like the 6 characters to have the pattern below:

```
New_Filed
A1B2C3
```

Comment: Have you tried using `SUBSTRING(Field_name, 3, 6)`?

Comment: @FelixPamittan That would return `ABC123`, so technically not the expected output. That said, it's unclear what the expected output should be... I guess just first character, fourth character, second character, fifth character, third character, sixth character?

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't notice the output is different.

Comment: @ZLK, maybe OP want's the letters and numbers in alternate order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this create right result but maybe someone can using some regex or what

```
SELECT CONCAT(
          SUBSTRING(field_name, 3, 1),
          SUBSTRING(field_name, 6, 1),
          SUBSTRING(field_name, 4, 1),
          SUBSTRING(field_name, 7, 1),
          SUBSTRING(field_name, 5, 1),
          SUBSTRING(field_name, 8, 1) ) AS New_Field 
  FROM yourtable
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18d20/2/0)

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, I believe this will work. I haven't made it working yet since there are some control conditions that are preventing me from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *Mid* in a query in Access (or VBA):

```
New_Field: Mid([Field_Name], 3, 1) & Mid([Field_Name], 6, 1) & Mid([Field_Name], 4, 1) & Mid([Field_Name], 7, 1) & Mid([Field_Name], 5, 1) & Mid([Field_Name], 8, 1)
```

Comment: "I am using MS SQL Server."

Comment: So you removed the MS Access tag. Thanks.